# using substring with regex mysql

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I am trying to get year (yyyy) from text/string in the column "title" but for some reason can't get following query to work:

```
select substring(title,LOCATE(REGEXP '[(][0-9]{4}[)]',title),4) from videos
```

title column has following values:

```
abc abc 2001 abc
xyz (2002) xyz
```

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: `REGEXP` can only be used to _match_ patterns, not extract them.  You will need to find another way.  MySQL may not be the best place to scrub your data.

Comment: @BillKarwin Most of the answers in your link aren't relevant to this question.

Comment: Why is this tagged `tsql`?

Comment: @BillKarwin your duplication is not relevant